# How can I do avoid this behavior every time that I type something on the input?

Tags: html, ionic-framework

how can I do to avoid [this behavior](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QS_p5bXSn2I&feature=youtu.be) ?

as you can see everytime that I type something, at the right appears a cancel button (x) and the height of the input increments, that's what I want to avoid.

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-positive bar-subheader">
  <label class="item-input-wrapper">
    <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
    <input type="text"
           placeholder="Sports finder...">
    <button class="button button-clear"
            ng-click="query = ''">
      <div ng-show="query">
        <i class="ion-close-circled assertive animated flipInY"></i>
      </div>
    </button>
  </label>
</ion-header-bar>
```

and there is the exact same code I am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to auto answer my question because I just did it, just in case any one else need it some time.

all I did: remove `label` and put `div` instead with the same `classes`, and also remove the `button` at all.

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-positive bar-subheader">
  <div class="item-input-wrapper">
    <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
    <input type="text"
           placeholder="Sports finder...">
      <div ng-show="query" ng-click="query = ''">
        <i class="ion-close-circled assertive animated flipInY"></i>
      </div>
  </div>
</ion-header-bar>
```